# Can $\frac{2u\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{g\cos\beta}=\frac{u\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{g\sin\beta}$ be reduced to $2\tan(\alpha-\beta)\tan\beta=1$?

Tags: trigonometry

Can $\frac{2u\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{g\cos\beta}=\frac{u\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{g\sin\beta}$ be reduced to $2\tan(\alpha-\beta)\tan\beta=1$?

The closest I can get is: $$\tan\alpha\tan\beta-2\tan^2{\beta}=1$$

Is this correct so far?

If not where did I go wrong? If so where does one go from here?

Comment: Just multiply both sides by the reciprocal of the RHS.

Comment: Great , I see that now. But can my final expression also be reduced to the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer can be changed to asked form.

$2(\tan({\alpha-\beta}))\tan\beta=1$

$⇔2(\tan\alpha-\tan\beta)\tan\beta=1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta$

$⇔\tan\alpha\tan\beta-2\tan^2\beta=1 $

Answer (score 3):

Cancelling $$u,g\ne 0$$ we have
$$2\tan(\alpha-\beta)\tan(\beta)=1$$ (after dividing by $\cos(\alpha-\beta)$ and multiplying by $\sin(\beta)$).

Comment: Great , I see that now. But can my final expression also be reduced to the correct answer?